# Preventing jumping when adding and removing table rows with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a bit of an issue with adding and removing table rows with JQuery.

Essentially what I am wanting to do is have a table with a fixed number of rows (e.g., 25) and I want to add new data every so often.

To do this I am removing the last row in the table and adding a new row to the top of the table.

The desired effect is fine for my needs, but there is one issue.

If I scroll down the page and have the top half of the table out of view (beyond the top of the browser window), but the bottom half in view (at the top of the browser window), the browser seems to scroll down when a row is removed and added.

Basically it seems the browser is "fixating" itself onto a row. Then, as that row is getting moved down the table, the browser follows it causing an undesired jumping effect.

Is there a way to prevent this, or is there a better way to implement the table?

HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%" id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>Dave</td>
    ...
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function addRow() {
  var tradeTable = $('#mytable');
  var rowCount = $('#mytable tr').length;
  var html = "<tr><td>Dave"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)+"</td></tr>";
  if (rowCount >= 40) {
    $('#mytable tr:last').remove();
    $('#mytable > tbody > tr:first').before(html);
  } else {
    $('#mytable > tbody > tr:first').before(html);
  }
}

setInterval(addRow, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```js
function addRow() {
  var tradeTable = $('#mytable');
  var rowCount = $('#mytable tr').length;
  var html = "<tr><td>Dave"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1)+"</td></tr>";
  if (rowCount >= 40) {
    $('#mytable tr:last').slideUp("slow",function(){
      $(this).remove();
    });
    $('#mytable > tbody > tr:first').before(html);
  } else {
    $('#mytable > tbody > tr:first').before(html);
  }
}
```

Use `jQuery slideDown` method before removing a `tr`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @BytesGuy . Please create a jsfiddle so that I can help you out better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't seem to work for me. Here is a jsfiddle - once 40 rows are populated you will see the issue if you scroll down enough to have the last few rows in view https://jsfiddle.net/frdd1x3r/

Comment: @BytesGuy . I'm not able to replicate the issue. Use `slideUp` instead of `slideDown`.